# How can I integrate custom module loading with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, amd

I'm using Webpack 1 for a frontend project and I have a legacy internal Javascript library which uses its own module system similar to AMD. A module is defined with a code similar to this:

```
MyLib.define('module id', ['my', 'module', 'deps'], function (my, module, deps) { /* module code */});
```

Then you can use the modules with a code like this:

```
MyLib.require(['dep1', 'dep2'], function (dep1, dep2) {});
```

I would like to be able to use MyLib along with all the other CommonJS modules I'm already using. Can webpack support this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Webpack doesn't support custom module formats (if someone else knows otherwise, I'd love to be proven wrong, though).

You perhaps could work around this by writing a [Webpack loader](https://webpack.js.org/development/how-to-write-a-loader/) or a [Babel plugin](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook) that converts the syntax to one of the module formats that Webpack supports. The latter is what Babel used to do for ES6 imports before Webpack supported them out of the box - it'd just transform them into CommonJS `require` calls.

Comment: I see, this seems like an elegant solution but it's probably going to be though if you have zero experience with Babel plugins. I'm now thinking to convert all the lib to CommonJS format, do you see any downside with that approach?

Comment: @sangaran: If you're going to go through and convert them manually rather than try to load them as is, I'd either choose CommonJS or ES2015 imports/exports (the former is supported by Webpack 1 and 2, the latter is supported by Webpack 2 or Webpack 1 with babel-loader). The latter is probably a better bet for the future, as it's an official JS spec, but CommonJS isn't going away any time soon due to it being used in Node.js. AMD doesn't really have a lot of traction these days (and I personally find it a pain to work with).

Comment: Yes, I think moving away from AMD it's the best bet for present and future development. Thanks!

Comment: @sangaran: No problem! One last tip - if you're going to be migrating a lot of code, Facebook's [codemod](https://github.com/facebook/codemod) tool might come in useful.